# como omitir valores en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

intento obtener un arreglo de promedios de una lista pero existen algunos vacios entonces como condiciono de que no use eso valores vacios

lista =  [1,"",1,2,4,""]

como agregar un if ala instrucción para que no use los NoneType y salga error

```
promedio = [sum(lista[:i+1])/float(i+1) for i in range(len(lista)-1)]
```

este es error que me marca

```
promedio = [sum(lista[:i+1])/float(i+1) for i in range(len(lista)-1)]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Hola luis te invito a leer el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Trata de ser más especifico, por ejemplo que te parece si agregas un ejemplo de lo que tiene en el array lista.

Comment: Luis tal y como comenta Jorgesys sería de mucha ayuda que agregaras un pequeño ejemplo de la lista y su salida esperada. ¿Estas intentando calcular la media móvil? (con tu código el último elemento de la lista no entra en el cálculo...) Es importante que indiques si solo puedes usar Python estándar o si usas otras bibliotecas como NumPy, Pandas o SciPy. Se puede usar `filter`, pasar a 0 los valores `None`, usar compresión de listas con un condicional para eliminarlos de la suma, etc...

Comment: @LuisAlbertoAcosta revisa [answer], El idioma oficial de este sitio es español.

Answer (score 1):

lo que se podria hacer es lo siguiente.

1. Eliminar lo que no queres por medio de un filter
2. Realizar el cálculo del promedio aplicando un reduce y dividiendo luego por la longitud de la lista que previamente ha sido depurada.

   ```
        lista=[1,None,1,2,4,""]
        newLista=filter(lambda x:not x in ("",None),lista)
        print(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,newLista)/len(newLista))
   ```

Este código funciona OK para lo que planteas.

Saludos.